# How to use spring boot jpa without auto_increment ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Field 'id' doesn't have a default value.

I'm getting this error when using jpa repo `save()` method to update.

Here's my entity for the ID

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
int orderID;
```

The problem is, i'm using a table without `auto_increment` for the id field.
And when i try to delete the `@GeneratedValue` annotation i'm getting:

```
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So is there any way i can use jpa to update entity when the id is not `auto_increment`, and also without using native update query?

---

Here is how i do select first and then update:

```
List<OrderModel> orderList = orderRepo.findAllVoidTransaction("-1"); 
for(OrderModel order: orderList) {  
    order.setOrderStatus("-3");
    order.setModifiedDate(StringUtil.getStringDate());
    orderRepo.save(order);
}
```

Comment: In that case you need to set Id in entity object by your self otherwise it will be zero and cause exception.

Comment: I think it's already set, because before update by using the save() method, i do select from the db first by using find method.
Also the id of the first row is '0' in my table.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: Why don't you use the GenerationType.AUTO? I think GenerationType.IDENTITY should be used, when you want that your database generates the ID, but it doesn't in your case.